# Order of listeners in doubly-connected component

Tags: redux, react-redux

Let us have two react-redux `connect`s composed with some other higher order components:

```
export default compose(
  connect((state) => {
    console.log('In outer connect')
    return state
  }),
  requireAuthState(isLoggedIn, '/'),
  connect(
    (state) => {
      console.log('In inner connect')
      return state
    },
    (dispatch, props) => ({
      ...
    })
  ),
)(Profile)
```

I have noticed that if `state` is changed, the listener related to the inner connect is called first. In this case, the console log would be:

```
In inner connect
In outer connect
```

Is this a bug or a feature or one should not assume anything about the order in which react-redux handles re-rendering of connected components?

It is causing problems for me in this particular case. The `requireAuthState` h.o.c. sometimes (depending on the app state) does not render its children. However, the inner connect tries to re-render anyways, which then results in an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a known issue with React-Redux up through v4.  The wrapper components subscribe in `componentDidMount`, which is fired bottom-to-top, so it's quite possible that child components can subscribe before their parents.

The upcoming React-Redux v5 (which will [hopefully be released shortly](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/473)) fixes this issue by enforcing top-down subscriptions, which also helps improve performance.  See [React-Redux PR #416](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/pull/416) for further details, as well as the [release notes](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/releases).